# How to get Latitude/Longitude from Web App?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a Web ADF application and I simply want the user to have the ability to click on the map and a Popup window displays the Latitide/Longitude values where the users click on the map.  How can I do this?

Comment: What projection does your map use?

Comment: The projection my map uses is NAD 1927 UTM Zone 15N

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what Web Map API you are using.

Check its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/introduction.html), [Bing Maps](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/) and [Yahoo Maps](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/ajax/). Each has a different API.  Choose one and start coding.  There are lots of samples for what you want to do for each of these API's.

[here](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/adf/dotnet/samples_start.htm) is the online sample link for the ESRI ADF

Comment: Thanks but I cannot venture away from the current environment which is Web ADF .NET  If there is a way to do this, please let me know

Comment: check the ESRI sample apps http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/adf/dotnet/samples_start.htm

Comment: Hi, I've checked that link but I my problem is that I'm using a GeoCortex Web ADF app.  I don't really know how to incorportate those extra classes because GeoCortex pre-compiles all their would-be classes into dll's

Comment: hmmm, well, thats something I have no experience with, sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

Among several ways, one could be that (assuming that you have a table containing, atleast, 3 columns, MapID, Longitude, Latitude), you can:

1. Create an image map of your world map
2. Retrieve the longitude/latitude against the id of the image where mouse was clicked.
3. Display the long/lat.

Also, checkout [Bing Maps ASP.NET Control](http://bingmapsasp.codeplex.com/) and [Developing a .NET Application Using Bing Maps Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but I'm a novice programmer.  Is there a way to get the access to the onclick event of the map control?  And if so shouldn't I be able to get a mapPoint of where the user clicked to return an X and Y?  From there I would just need to convert that XY to Lat Long